# IBM Maximo - sending HTML email

Tags: java, html, maximo

I need to send HTML e-mail from Maxima, but as a result, only text without tags and without a table comes to the mail, how I can do it true?

Code example:

```
package com.vetasi.testPackage;

import psdi.server.MXServer;
import psdi.server.SimpleCronTask;
import psdi.util.logging.MXLogger;
import psdi.util.logging.MXLoggerFactory;

public class Test1 extends SimpleCronTask{

    MXLogger logger = MXLoggerFactory.getLogger("com.test.TestReportCron");

    @Override
    public void cronAction(){

        String message1 = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\r\n" + 
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n" + 
            " <head>\r\n" + 
            "  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\r\n" + 
            "  <title>Title</title>\r\n" + 
            "  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>\r\n" + 
            "</head>\r\n" + 
            "<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\">\r\n" + 
            " <table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\r\n" + 
            "  <tr>\r\n" + 
            "   <td>\r\n" + 
            "    Hello!\r\n" + 
            "   </td>\r\n" + 
            "  </tr>\r\n" + 
            " </table>\r\n" + 
            "</body>\r\n" + 
            "</html>"   ;


        try{
        MXServer.sendEMail("Misha89uatest@gmail.com", "maxadmin@us.ibm.com", "Hello my friend", message1);

         }catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Result:
[Comes e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eMbH.png)

When I using the Java Mail API, everything works fine, but there is much more code, and it is preferable to do in Maximo methods Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your `mxe.email.content.type` system prop setup correctly? See this: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-mxeemailcontenttype-system-property

Comment: I had mxe.email.content.type = "text/html; charset=UTF-8" (without the quotes) and it was not correctly value...  mxe.email.content.type = "text/html" (without the quotes) this is correctly and it is working! Thank you for you tooltip.